# How do I access "the brick game" in Trace Vector?

Tags: trace-vector

Some of the Steam achievements for Trace Vector mention "the brick game", but I can't find any game mode other than Adventure and Endless. How do I access the brick game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone on the Steam forums helped me with this one.

Each time you finish a world, you enter a dialogue with your ship. If you ignore the dialogue and press the up or down key, a Breakout style game will appear in the console of your ship.

You can move the "paddle" with the up and down keys. Each time the full group of bricks is cleared, one point is awarded and the bricks reset.